# LMR64010 wrong feedback voltage and wrong output voltage

Tags: power-supply

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr64010.pdf?ts=1612008208765&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) can be found here.

The typical application circuit is shown:
[image]

And my schematic:
[image]

The difference is SHDN pin is directly linked to input, since I never want it to be off.

The layout:
[image]

The issue is that with 3.7V I get 0.5V on the feedback pin, although the datasheet specifies 1.2V, and output voltage is 4.5V. Board heats up around that region as well. I have not found any shorts.

The PCB:
[image]

I have followed the design guide, and yet something is up, and I cannot seem to figure out what. If you have any suggestions regarding what else to check, please do tell

Comment: You did not follow the Recommended PCB Component Layout with thermal tracks

Comment: What output load current is being taken from the 15 volts?

Comment: Where is the input capacitor? Why there is 4 voltage setting resistors? What are the parameters for the coil?

Comment: Is there any sign of switching activity at all? Have you disconnected the output from everything else and tested both halves in isolation? (i.e. test the PSU on its own, and the customer from a 15V lab supply to see its current demand)

Comment: Gentlemen, the inductor was shorted.

Answer (score 1):

> *If you have any suggestions regarding what else to check, please do
> tell*

Check is that your output current is not too high: -

[image]

Sure, your input voltage is a little higher at 3.7 volts but, realistically it might mean that you could achieve 115 mA for the output load current at 15 volts.

Look at the losses - with 100 mA and 15 volts (a power of 1.5 watts) at the output, the input power will be about 40% more so, that's 600 mW dissipated in the chip and, that will **get warm without significant copper around the device** to take heat away.

You might get around 65% efficiency at 3.7 volts of course so do some math and see if your output current is actually demanding too much from this feeble (but nice) little chip.

You should also look at the inductor losses and check that its self resonant frequency is not approaching that of the switching frequency used.

There is also a serious doubt about pin 2 (ground on the chip). Your layout does not show it connected anywhere: -

[image]

Comment: The ground is connected, I hid away the polygon pours to make a sensible picture. The output voltage is shown at no load. Nothing is connected to it

Comment: Not showing ground is not sensible @Atizs . Check again that nothing is connected then double check!

Comment: The inductor was shorted

Comment: Your question has been answered. You asked for suggestions of what else to check and good information was supplied. Admittedly nobody guessed that the inductor was shorted but, as a good user of stack exchange, I expect you to award yourself the points by making an answer and supplying an upvote for people stepping in to try and help you. Anything less would appear to be mean. But, congrats on finding the problem.

Comment: Sure thing Andy

Comment: You should still leave your answer I reckon. It’s the right answer to your problem and it might be the right answer to future readers of this question @Atizs

Answer (score 1):

Two bad assumptions

- missing low ESR input cap.
- lack of thermal dissipating tracks in your layout.

This results in 250'C/W case temp rise

[image]

Always follow recommended layout. No exceptions unless you understand the consequences.

Comment: Yes, I did not follow that part, true. I can understand that it could cause some heat issues, but is it truly enough to produce wrong output right off the bat?

Comment: Consider the switch Pd during startup may be taking >2A until Cout is charged up. What controls your input voltage risetime? dry contact? What is your switch Pd during startup How many Watts?

Comment: The inductor was shorted

Comment: Makes sense, the pads had too small a gap